# Flex remove Child

Tags: apache-flex

I have a panel with id "panel"
and in this panel I have a scroller with id "scroller"
and in this scroller I have a chart with id "chart"

I want to remove the chart 
I tried

```
panel.removeChild(chart);
```

I get this error: the displayObject specified must be a child of the caller.

I tried

```
scroller.removeChild(chart);
```

I get another error: try removeElement()
and the remove element doesn't work

how can I remove this chart?

Answer (score 1):

try removing from the scroller.viewport. 
Please post the exact code so that we can help you better.

Comment: I added a`<s:HGroup>`  with id group in the scroller
then I removed the chart :

    group.removeElement(chart);
and that works :)

Comment: You can also add an id to the chart and try removing it directly, The same way as id.removeElement();